# Tikz with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, gnuplot

Hi Guys I want to draw a function with 1 variables and the sum of this so basically my function is this:

```
sum(11/(2*k-1)*sin(2*50*\%pi*(2*k-1)*x)
```

I wanted to make it with Gnuplot but that gave me an error massage:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'test.pgf-plotlot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. }
```

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel = $t$,
    xtick = {-.5,.5},
    xticklabels = {$-\frac{T}{2}$, $\frac{T}{2}$},
    ytick = {-1,-.5,.5,1},
    yticklabels = {$-A$, $-\frac{A}{2}$, $\frac{A}{2}$, $A$},
    domain = -.75:.75,
    samples = 200,
    ]
    \addplot[mark = none] gnuplot {(x - floor(x +.5)) < 0 ? -1 : 1};
    \addlegendentry{Signal}
    \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8}{%
      \addplot+[mark = none] gnuplot[raw gnuplot] {%
        set samples 200;
        fourier(k, x) = (11 /(2*k-1)*sin(2*50*\%pi*(2*k-1)*x)
        plot[-.75:.75] sum [k=0:\i] fourier(k,x)};
      \addlegendentryexpanded{\number\numexpr 2*\i+1\relax{} first terms}
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in the gnuplot code.  It should be just `pi` instead of `\%pi` and there is closing parenthesis and a semicolon missing after the definition of `fourier`.  I removed the outer parentheses of `fourier` and added the semicolon.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel = $t$,
    xtick = {-.5,.5},
    xticklabels = {$-\frac{T}{2}$, $\frac{T}{2}$},
    ytick = {-1,-.5,.5,1},
    yticklabels = {$-A$, $-\frac{A}{2}$, $\frac{A}{2}$, $A$},
    domain = -.75:.75,
    samples = 200,
    ]
    \addplot[mark = none] gnuplot {(x - floor(x +.5)) < 0 ? -1 : 1};
    \addlegendentry{Signal}
    \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8}{%
      \addplot+[mark = none] gnuplot[raw gnuplot] {%
        set samples 200;
        fourier(k, x) = 11 /(2*k-1)*sin(2*50*pi*(2*k-1)*x);
        plot[-.75:.75] sum [k=0:\i] fourier(k,x);
      };
      \addlegendentryexpanded{\number\numexpr 2*\i+1\relax{} first terms}
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: same error as before but thanks

Comment: this error appears by every gnuplot i will make i copied a few examples and non of them worked